# Dynamically re-load Deno cached module

Tags: deno

Wondering how I can dynamically purge and replace a module loaded into Deno via import. In Node there's a global cache that I can just delete the value and reimport. All its dependencies continue operating with the updated value. I've found a few ways ie. deleting the reference and letting it be garbage collected but that's not a dependable way for my application.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question but you can reload cached modules with the Deno CLI using `deno cache --reload` and reload either the entire cache or specific modules.